# new to android - not able to display picture in imageview twice

Tags: android

after clicking on a button and taking a picture, I want to display it in an imageview as in the following:

```
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
ImageView myImage1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivReturnedPic);
myImage1.setImageBitmap(bMap);
```

This works great the first time you take a picture, the picture displays fine on the screen. But if I click on the button again to take a second picture, it just errors out on the phone. Emulator seems to work fine, so I have no error message to share with you. Do you think ADB bridge might be helpful in this case ?  Now, if I comment out the following piece of code, no error:

```
myImage1.setImageBitmap(bMap);
```

May be because bMap is null ? Can someone help me in this issue ?

Comment: Stack trace or it didn't happen.

Comment: Check if `bMap` is null before assigning to the Image Object?

Comment: You can debug the code, while connected to a real device. Place a breakpoint at beginning, and step through line by line. You'll get to see what is null and what not. If you still can't figure out, post the rest of the code.

Comment: sorry im kind of new to android, how would i check if bMap is null?

Comment: i know how to put it in debug mode, but not sure how to check if bmap is null.

Comment: Add a log line, if (bMAp == null) Log.i("TAG","bMap is null");

Answer (score 0):

```
Check if bMap is null or not before assigning to ImageView
```

so try this

```
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
ImageView myImage1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivReturnedPic);
if(bMap!=null)
 {
  myImage1.setImageBitmap(bMap);
 }
else
{
Log.d("Checking Bitmap","bMap is null"); 
}
```

Comment: but what if bMap is null... then what?

Comment: ok i just pasted the code - i still errored  out. that means that bmap is not null.

Comment: You should use a TAG for the first parameter of the Log, either a program or class tag (set a const string TAG somewhere)

Comment: Also Fish Boy, it's really hard to help you without a stack trace of the exception.